# get date string and convert to date angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date

I'm trying to get string in format `mm/dd/yyyy` from input:

```
<input type="text"
       name="date" 
       class="input-date"
       ng-model="myCtrl.item.date">
```

and I have addItem function:

```
function addItem () {
    vm.newItem = {
        date : '',
    };
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You can use input `type="date"`. What is problem?

Comment: Where do you want to get the date in pattern `mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 <input type="date"
   name="new_date" 
   class="input-date"
   ng-model="myCtrl.item.date"
   ng-blur="myCtrl.onBlurAddItem($event)">
```

It should work!